# Is there any function or way to retrieve table names from Snowflake in the order of referential integrity (FK) dependencies?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, data-lake

I would like to retrieve table names from a given schema in the sorted order based on their foreign key dependencies. For example, if I have three following tables created in Snowflake

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_X
(
    COL_A CHAR(18),
    COL_B CHAR(18),
    COL_C CHAR(18),
    CONSTRAINT XPKTAB_X PRIMARY KEY (COL_A, COL_B)
);

CREATE TABLE TAB_Z
(
    COL_D CHAR(18),
    COL_E CHAR(18),
    COL_F CHAR(18),
    COL_G CHAR(18),
    COL_A CHAR(18),
    COL_B CHAR(18),
    CONSTRAINT XPKTAB_Z PRIMARY KEY (COL_D, COL_E, COL_A, COL_B),
    CONSTRAINT R_1 FOREIGN KEY (COL_A, COL_B) REFERENCES TAB_X (COL_A, COL_B)
);

CREATE TABLE TAB_B
(
    COL_H CHAR(18),
    COL_I CHAR(18),
    COL_J CHAR(18),
    COL_K CHAR(18),
    COL_D CHAR(18),
    COL_E CHAR(18),
    COL_A CHAR(18),
    COL_B CHAR(18),
    CONSTRAINT XPKTAB_B PRIMARY KEY (COL_H, COL_I, COL_D, COL_E, COL_A, COL_B),
    CONSTRAINT R_2 FOREIGN KEY (COL_D, COL_E, COL_A, COL_B) REFERENCES TAB_Z (COL_D, COL_E, COL_A, COL_B)
);
```

In this scenario, if I execute a `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;` query then it would return me the table names in alphabetically sorted order, that will be.

```
TAB_B
TAB_X
TAB_Z
```

But I want the correct order of creation, that is:

```
TAB_X
TAB_Z
TAB_B
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Update:
I cannot achieve this by sorting the table names based on CREATION timestamp, for example, if I create the Tables as following:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_A
(
    COL_1 CHAR(18),
    COL_2 CHAR(18),
    COL_3 CHAR(18),
    COL_6 CHAR(18),
    COL_8 CHAR(18),
    COL_12 CHAR(18)
);

ALTER TABLE TAB_A
    ADD CONSTRAINT XPKCOL_C PRIMARY KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

CREATE TABLE TAB_C
(
    COL_1 CHAR(18),
    COL_2 CHAR(18),
    COL_3 CHAR(18),
    COL_6 CHAR(18),
    COL_8 CHAR(18),
    COL_11 CHAR(18)
);

ALTER TABLE TAB_C
    ADD CONSTRAINT XPKCOL_X PRIMARY KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

CREATE TABLE TAB_O
(
    COL_1 CHAR(18),
    COL_2 CHAR(18),
    COL_3 CHAR(18),
    COL_6 CHAR(18),
    COL_8 CHAR(18),
    COL_12 CHAR(18)
);

ALTER TABLE TAB_O
    ADD CONSTRAINT XPKCOL_A PRIMARY KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

CREATE TABLE TAB_X
(
    COL_1 CHAR(18),
    COL_2 CHAR(18),
    COL_3 CHAR(18),
    COL_4 CHAR(18),
    COL_5 CHAR(18)
);

ALTER TABLE TAB_X
    ADD CONSTRAINT XPKTAB_A PRIMARY KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3);

CREATE TABLE TAB_Z
(
    COL_1 CHAR(18),
    COL_2 CHAR(18),
    COL_3 CHAR(18),
    COL_6 CHAR(18),
    COL_8 CHAR(18),
    COL_9 CHAR(18),
    COL_0 CHAR(18)
);

ALTER TABLE TAB_Z
    ADD CONSTRAINT XPKTAB_Z PRIMARY KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

ALTER TABLE TAB_A
    ADD CONSTRAINT R_4 FOREIGN KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8) REFERENCES TAB_C (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

ALTER TABLE TAB_C
    ADD CONSTRAINT R_2 FOREIGN KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8) REFERENCES TAB_Z (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

ALTER TABLE TAB_O
    ADD CONSTRAINT R_3 FOREIGN KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8) REFERENCES TAB_C (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_6, COL_8);

ALTER TABLE TAB_Z
    ADD CONSTRAINT R_1 FOREIGN KEY (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) REFERENCES TAB_X (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3);
```

Comment: Why don't you sort it by created or last_altered column?

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view has a CREATED timestamp. You can return them ordered by timestamp:

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by CREATED;
```

If you're looking for something else, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there are certain scenarios where it would not work. Please see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Join it with information_schema.table_constraints and filter and sort on key type to get the information.

Comment: That does not work, I already tried and had a "duh!!" moment. That sorting would work on 'PRIMARY KEY' and 'FORIEGN KEY' and since there would be more than one TABLE with these key types and TABLES with both keys, the returned result will not be consistent and change every time.